# Programmatically changing screen lock timeout

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, system-preferences

In my Cocoa application I would like to access and change the computer's screen lock timeout setting. Changing it in System Preferences does not require the user to enter the admin password.

[image: System Preferences screenshot - Screen lock timeout]

Unfortunately I couldn't find any information in the documentation, and I'm not sure what topic I should look into (security settings / prefPane programming).
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to change the value or are you trying to prevent sleep?

Comment: @CRD Trying to change the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSMutableDictionary* plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/new/Library/Preferences/com.apple.screensaver.plist"];
[plistDict setObject:@"1" forKey:@"askForPassword"];
[plistDict setObject:@"3600" forKey:@"askForPasswordDelay"];
[plistDict writeToFile:@"/Users/new/Library/Preferences/com.apple.screensaver.plist" atomically:YES];
```

or From terminal

```
defaults write com.apple.screensaver askForPasswordDelay 5
```

Comment: I think it doesn't take any effect immediately at least on OS X 10.9. After sleep the OS still uses the previous value instead of the new one. It looks like it needs some trigger.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer apparently works for some, but on 10.8 it fails if you are using FileVault. The setting will stick, but it won't actually take effect until you launch System Preferences. Luckily, there's a way to 'touch' the setting after you are done:

```
- (void)touchSecurityPreferences;
{
    NSAppleScript *kickSecurityPreferencesScript = [[[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource: @"tell application \"System Events\" to tell security preferences to set require password to wake to true"] autorelease];
    [kickSecurityPreferencesScript executeAndReturnError:nil];
}
```

**Edit** Turns out this only works for going from a non-zero setting to zero setting. I assume this is a security thing. To go the other way, launching System Preferences is the only way.

**Edit 2** Here's code for launching System Preferences, should you want to do so:

```
- (void)launchAndQuitSecurityPreferences;
{
    // necessary for screen saver setting changes to take effect on file-vault-enabled systems when going from a askForPasswordDelay setting of zero to a non-zero setting
    NSAppleScript *kickSecurityPreferencesScript = [[[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:
                                                     @"tell application \"System Preferences\"\n"
                                                     @"     tell anchor \"General\" of pane \"com.apple.preference.security\" to reveal\n"
                                                     @"     activate\n"
                                                     @"end tell\n"
                                                     @"delay 0\n"
                                                     @"tell application \"System Preferences\" to quit"] autorelease];
    [kickSecurityPreferencesScript executeAndReturnError:nil];
}
```