# Lock screen from command-line as same as Keychain Access does on OS X

Tags: macos, cocoa

I noticed that `/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\ Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -suspend` and Keychain Access's Lock Screen (open its Preferences, check 'Show keychain status in menu bar' then hit Lock Screen from the status bar icon.) has different functionality. Is there any way to run Keychain Access's Lock Screen from command-line through Terminal.app or Cocoa API?

Mac OS 10.9. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just found a solution for this: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/123738/72534

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main () {
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:@"/Applications/Utilities/Keychain Access.app/Contents/Resources/Keychain.menu"];

    Class principalClass = [bundle principalClass];

    id instance = [[principalClass alloc] init];

    [instance performSelector:@selector(_lockScreenMenuHit:) withObject:nil];

    return 0;
}
```

Save as `lockscreen.m` and compile with:

```
clang -framework Foundation -o lockscreen lockscreen.m
```

Works perfectly, as it just calls the same routine as the status bar icon.

Comment: Please post the relevant part of the solution from the link, if the link becomes invalid, then this answer will be useless.

Comment: On Xcode, I got `No known instance method for selector '_lockScreenMenuHit:'` by default but with compiling `clang` it worked!

Comment: This warning is generated, because the compiler can't make sure, that the object implements a method called '_lockScreenMenuHit:'. Indeed if apple changes the implementation of the principal class in this bundle, the program might crash. I guess there is a way in obj-c to check for the existence of the method at runtime, but i just wanted the example to be as simple as possible.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Is there a way to trigger this directly from the command-line, similar to the less desirable example in the question? I tried `/Applications/Utilities/Keychain\ Access.app/Contents/Resources/Keychain.menu/Contents/MacOS/Keychain` but got an error 'cannot execute binary file'. Is there an option or something that would have the same effect as the solution? It just seems convoluted to create a binary executable that activates part of another binary executable.

Comment: I don't think that this is possible. The Keychain menu binary contains plugin code that is intended to be executed by some host application (in this case something like the menu bar system of macOS). Therefore the binary doesn't contain an entry point and can't be executed directly.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore on 10.13 because the MenuExtra has been removed. This works instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26492632/368409

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16368803/447697 may be of use.

Essentially:

```
io_registry_entry_t entry = IORegistryEntryFromPath(kIOMasterPortDefault, "IOService:/IOResources/IODisplayWrangler");

if (entry) {
    IORegistryEntrySetCFProperty(entry, CFSTR("IORequestIdle"), kCFBooleanTrue);
    IOObjectRelease(entry);
}
```

Comment: As the original answer mentioned the code brings sleep mode, not exactly the Lock Screen which normally would ask you password whether you've unchecked 'Require password' on Security & Privacy from System Preferences. Thanks for the comment though.

Answer (score 0):

As it has been stated above, the error "no known instance method for selector '_lockScreenMenuHit:'" happens because the compiler can't tell if such method exists inside "instance" before runtime. To solve this problem I created a subclass of NSBundle which I named "newPrincipalClass" and inside that class I created an instance method called -(void)_lockScreenMenuHit:(id)a.

The modified main file has the following code:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "newPrincipalClass.h"

int main()
{
    NSBundle* bundle =[NSBundle bundleWithPath:@"/Applications/Utilities/Keychain Access.app/Contents/Resources/Keychain.menu"];
    Class newPrincipalClass = [bundle principalClass];
    id instance =[[newPrincipalClass alloc] init];
    [instance _lockScreenMenuHit:NULL];

    return 0
}
```

So, I create "instance" with my new subclass "newPrincipalClass" which includes a method called "_lockScreenMenuHit:". Now when the compiler checks inside "instance", it finds the method's name so no error is displayed. And there you have it, the program runs with no problem!