# OSX: Lock the screen programmatically

Tags: macos, appleevents

I'm looking for a way to lock the user screen programmatically without putting the Mac asleep.
Right now, i'm able to trigger the lock screen with the kAESleep event but it's more a hack and it put the computer asleep.
Is it possible ?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lock screen by api in mac os X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976520/lock-screen-by-api-in-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 1):

Configure the screensaver to require a password immediately after it starts, then start the screensaver programmatically.  I have it programmed to a keyboard shortcut to help my Windows folks transition to using real computers ;).

Comment: Thanks for your response. The thing is that the screensaver is like turning off the screen, wich is close to what kAESleep do. I would like to just invoke the login screen (the one you got after you wake up your mac) programmatically

Comment: Fair enough.  I'll be curious to see if anyone else knows how to do so.  In the mean time this may be a little more to liking, though it obviously is still little different than the above:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/80058/lock-screen-command-one-liner

Answer (score 0):

The following AppleScript will do it for you.  Note that because of security limitations of OSX, AppleScript pauses for five seconds before it executes an UI function, so it takes a small while to function.  I'm using Quicksilver to bind it to a hotkey.

(As a bonus, this script will also pause a couple of your music players.  Feel free to remove those lines.)

```
#
#  Tell our noisy programs to shut up
#
tell application "Spotify"
    pause
end tell

tell application "iTunes"
    pause
end tell

#
#  Lock up the screen without going to sleep.  Needs that Keychain Access
#  is set up properly.
#
tell application "System Events" to tell process "SystemUIServer" to click (first menu item of menu 1 of ((click (first menu bar item whose description is "Keychain menu extra")) of menu bar 1) whose title is "Lock Screen")
```

You will need to set up Keychain Access so that it has the lock icon on screen though.

Answer (score 0):

I was successfully able to lock the screen on macOS in python with the following

```
import ctypes, ctypes.util

login = ctypes.CDLL( '/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/login.framework/login' )
login.SACLockScreenImmediate()
```

I discovered this by scarce information on the Internet and trial-and-error. As far as I know, Apple doesn't document the `SACLockScreenImmediate()` function *at all*.

If anyone can find the official reference documentation for the "Login Framework" library, please drop it in the comments :)

##### Source

The is used in the BusKill app, which locks the screen when a magnetic breakaway connection in a USB Dead Man Switch is severed:

- https://github.com/BusKill/buskill-app/tree/master/src/packages/buskill