# Programmatically query macOS screen unlock (C API)

Tags: c, macos, terminal

Curious. Is there any way to programmatically query screen unlock events in macOS 14? Preferably with plain C?

My application is a plain terminal app. I know there's ways to monitor screen unlock events through NSNotification (Objective-C) but AFAIK that doesn't work for simple terminal apps and even if it did it would only wait for incoming events.

What I want is accessing the log for past screen unlock events, similarly to how `last(1)` can query the log for past login events.

Is this possible, at all? Does macOS Sonoma keep a log of screen unlock events around somewhere?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26492632/299924) work?

Comment: It does indeed work but it's not what I'm looking for (alas, it might point me in the right direction still).

What I'm looking for is a way to query when a user has disengaged the lockscreen, not engage the lockscreen myself programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this command :

```
log show --predicate '(eventMessage CONTAINS "unlockUI" OR eventMessage CONTAINS "LUI")' --last 24h | grep sessionUnlocked
```

Comment: Any way I can get this info through os_log?
Doing this from the terminal or forking out is wayyy too slow.

Comment: If you run with `--last 1m`, is it fast enough ?

Comment: Still slow and that way I can only get the last minute.
Ideally, I'd be able to grab a month or more worth of screen unlock events in a reasonable time.

Is there no API for that? I don't suppose os_log can print system log entries?